# How to NOT trigger applicationSignificantTimeChange at midnight

Tags: ios, swift, time

How to NOT trigger applicationSignificantTimeChange at midnight, but use it in all other cases?

This works as expected, but how to stop it on midnight or between (23:30 till 00:30)?

```
func applicationSignificantTimeChange(_ application: UIApplication) {
    NSLog("Application Significant Time Change")
    Manager.setupTime()
}
```

Comment: You can't prevent it. And depending on the state of your app, may not receive the notification at midnight. It would be best to update your question (don't reply in a comment) and describe what you are really trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot stop `applicationSignificantTimeChange` from triggering at midnight.

[From documentation:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622992-applicationsignificanttimechange)

> Examples of significant time changes include the arrival of **midnight**, an update of the time by a carrier, and the change to daylight savings time.

**Workaround:**

You can put if condition like below to check if current time is between 23:30 - 00:30 and ignore it.

```
func applicationSignificantTimeChange(_ application: UIApplication) {
    let currentTime = Date()
    let midnight = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: currentTime)
    let thirtyMinsBeforeMidnight = midnight.addingTimeInterval(-30*60)
    let thirtyMinutesAfterMidnight = midnight.addingTimeInterval(30*60)

    if currentTime.timeIntervalSince(thirtyMinsBeforeMidnight) >= 0 && currentTime.timeIntervalSince(thirtyMinutesAfterMidnight) <= 0 {
        // time between 23:30 - 00:30
    }
    else {
        // time is not between 23:30 - 00:30
        // do your stuff
        NSLog("Application Significant Time Change")
        Manager.setupTime()
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe in the use case being discussed, this probably would be the right code, but the comments may cause confusion. During a DST transition, 30 minutes after `.startOfDay` may not be 00:30. It may be 23:30 or 01:30. In the discussed problem, that may not really matter, but in many cases it may. If the real question were "is it currently between 23:30 and 0:30," you would need completely different code.

Comment: Just removed the comment that could have caused the confusion. Nice catch! I've mentioned, this is only a workaround and not a solution as requirement is odd. Obviously, OP needs to handle cases based on requirements.

Comment: Another issue with this answer is that the "arrival of midnight" notification may arrive late if the app is suspended. Or the notification may be combined with other time change notifications. It's also possible the user could change the time near midnight and this code would incorrectly ignore that notification. But the OP has not yet provided enough details to know if these are actually going to be issues or not.